# Excel exported as garbled PK zip file to browser

Tags: php, symfony

This is driving me crazy. I'm using a PHP function to download an Excel file. This works fine in my local environment and testing server, but on the production server, instead of downloading the spreadsheet, it prints a lot of garbled text to the browser window. It looks like the "PK" code for a zip file. The result is inconsistent. I reduce the number of columns and it works. Then I added one more column and it breaks. Then the next day it works. Then I add another column and it breaks. The same function works in other areas of the app, it's just when I try to export this one file.

This is a Symfony 4.4 app running on PHP 8.1. All environments should be identical.

```
        $filePath = $path . $fileName;

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', "attachment;filename={$fileName}");
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', "no-cache");
        $response->headers->set('Expires', "0");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "binary");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Length', filesize($filePath));
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $response->prepare($request);
        $response->setContent(readfile($filePath));
        $response->sendContent();
        unlink($filePath);

        return $response;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Instead of trying to set all those headers manually I just used the ResponseHeaderBag. Works now.

```
return $this->file("export/".$fileName, $fileName, ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/readfile) does not return the contents of the file, but rather outputs it directly so:

> ```php
> $response->setContent(readfile($filePath));
> ```

is definitely wrong.

Instead use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents):

```php
$response->setContent(file_get_contents($filePath));
```

I would refactor the code to read the file contents and set the `Content-Length` according to how many bytes `$fileContents` is:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($filePath);

$response->headers->set('Content-Length', strlen($fileContents));

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response->prepare($request);
$response->setContent($fileContents);
```

(strlen() always returns the number of bytes in a string, not characters).

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same result.